# How do I get a single file name out of a File Dialog object in VBA (for MS Access 2007)?

Tags: ms-access, vba, openfiledialog

How do I change my code to get the file name instead of the directory name? `openDialog.InitialFilename` gives me the directory name.
`openDialog.FileName` gives me the error "Method or data member not found".

```
Private Sub btnEditPhoto_Click()
    If (txtImageName > "") Then

        Application.FollowHyperlink txtImageName

    Else
        Dim openDialog As Office.FileDialog

        Set openDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

            openDialog.Filters.Clear
            openDialog.Filters.Add "JPEG Files", "*.jpg"

        Dim pickedFile As Boolean
            pickedFile = openDialog.Show

        If pickedFile Then
                txtImageName.SetFocus
                txtImageName.Text = openDialog.InitialFileName
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It's kind of confusing to edit your question to incorporate the answer, as at that point, your code does what you're asking for help on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want:

```
OpenDialog.SelectedItems.Item(1)
```

In place of:

```
OpenDialog.InitialFileName
```

As you have not allowed multiselect.

---

So:

```
''Reference Microsoft Office x.x Object Library
Dim openDialog As Office.FileDialog

Set openDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
openDialog.Filters.Clear
openDialog.Filters.Add "JPEG Files", "*.jpg"

If openDialog.Show Then
    ''SelectedItems is not zero based

    ''Do not use .Text property in MS Access except
    ''in special cases, then you will not have to set focus
    ''txtImageName.SetFocus

    txtImageName = openDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End If
```

If AllowMultiSelect is used, you need to iterate through SelectedItems

```
''Reference Microsoft Office x.x Object Library
Dim openDialog As Office.FileDialog
Dim i As Integer

Set openDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
'Use ctl or shift + click to select more than one file
openDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
openDialog.Filters.Clear
openDialog.Filters.Add "JPEG Files", "*.jpg"

If openDialog.Show Then
    For i = 1 To openDialog.SelectedItems.Count
        Imagelst = Imagelst & ";" & openDialog.SelectedItems(i)
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to select a single text file... this is what I did... it worked fine.

```
' Get the File
'----------------------------------------------------------
Dim dialog As Object
Dim pickedfile As Boolean
Dim myfile As String
Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With dialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Please pick the file to convert."
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.TXT"
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
    pickedfile = False
    pickedfile = .Show
    If pickedfile Then
    myfile = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End If
End With
'----------------------------------------------------------
```

Additionally... you can replace the dialog type with...

```
Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
```

and it worked equally well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Command135_Click()

Dim dialog As Object
Dim pickedfile As Boolean
Dim myfile As String
Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(1)
With dialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Please pick the file to convert."
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Picture Files", "*.Jpg"
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
    pickedfile = False
    pickedfile = .Show
    If pickedfile Then
    myfile = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End If
End With

Me.Form.Picture = myfile
End Sub


Command_135=Button Name
Me.Form.Picture = "The Control Name"
```

Comment: Give a brief description of the code that you have posted so that it is helpful to others.