# "Save as..." dialog box in MSAccess vba: how?

Tags: vba, ms-access, dialog, export, ms-access-2007

In MSAccess I've a mask with a button. When the user clicks on the button, the data in a table are exported on a .txt file:

```
Private Sub Command_Click()
Dim Rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim AField As DAO.Field
Dim TempStr As String
Dim FileNumber
FileNumber = FreeFile
Open "c:\table.txt" For Output As #FileNumber
Set Rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Tabella1", dbOpenForwardOnly)
Do While Not Rst.EOF
    For Each AField In Rst.Fields
        If (AField.Name <> "ID") Then
            TempStr = TempStr & AField.value & "    "
        End If
    Next
    Print #FileNumber, Left(TempStr, Len(TempStr) - 1)
    TempStr = ""
    Rst.MoveNext
Loop
Rst.Close
Set Rst = Nothing
Close #FileNumber
End Sub
```

It works, but I would display a "Save as..." dialog box by allowing the user to choose the file on which export the data.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set a reference to the Microsoft Office x.x Object Library and use FileDialog.

[FileDialog Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms250701(v=office.11))

```
Sub ShowFileDialog()
    Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog
    Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    With dlgOpen
        .InitialFileName = "Z:\docs\"
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

Also: [How do I get a single file name out of a File Dialog object in VBA (for MS Access 2007)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158675/how-do-i-get-a-single-file-name-out-of-a-file-dialog-object-in-vba-for-ms-acces/2158796#2158796)

Comment: Is there a different way (without using the object library)?

Comment: You can present them with a form (best) or InputBox and then do all the checking yourself as to whether a file already exists with that name or not and whether the name is legal and suitable.

Comment: msoFileDialogSaveAs is not supported in Access. The Filters Properties i.e. don't work - which is quiet substantial for SaveAs Dialog.

Answer (score 1):

For an API solution see here :
 http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0001.htm

Works well for me. 
Simply copy and paste in a new module.

Comment: As an aside, the code in the link will not work with 64 bit MS Access.