# How to upload file through microsoft access

Tags: ms-access, file-upload, upload

I have to design a microsoft access application. It has a form, this form will upload file and save to a folder. I don't want file has been save in database file. I only want save link to file.
I try search on google but no answer.
Please help me!

Comment: any file. sometimes is an images, sometimes is a document file

Comment: Is it necessary that it is used by Access?

Comment: You can use FileDialog to get a file path from the user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743224/save-as-dialog-box-in-msaccess-vba-how/11743428#11743428

Comment: Yes, because my customer only want use access. I have to make for my customer. I'm from a developing country.

Comment: Lets ask some questions, and start to plan this.

Where are the two folders-- the FROM folder, and the TO folder?  
Are they on the same machine C-drive?  
or at least on some network mapped drive on that machine?  

Then you could start the process with a Select popup to pick the From file.

Then copy it to the To folder,

Lastly insert a record in your msaccess table having
   date/time of copy
   userid of person doing copy
   filename of From file
   size in bytes of file
   foldername of To file
   etc